# Is there a Jackson json annotation for class?

Tags: java, jackson

I have controller class with method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createchild", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void createChild(@RequestBody Child child) {
    childService.createChild(child);
}
```

And it works, when i use this json:

```
{
    "childfullname":"Lok Maen",
    "password": "jfsddsf1",
    "phonenumber": "+79695426314"
}
```

But if i want to post something like this:

```
    {
    "another parameter": "123",
    "child": {
        "childfullname":"Lok Maen",
        "password": "jfsddsf1",
        "phonenumber": "+79155426314"
    }
}
```

it does not work.

Child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child", schema = "cheer")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "childid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childId;

    @JsonProperty("childfullname")
    @Column(name = "childfullname")
    private String childFullName;

    @JsonProperty("password")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
// another code
}
```

How can i modify code for posting one more parameter in json body?

Comment: Why not include `another parameter` in `Child` object? Are you looking for a parent-child relationship?

Comment: yes but i don't want to create additional field in class. And data base pattern is already complete

Comment: Then you can create a parent class with attributes as `another parameter` and `Child`. Your method should change to accept parent class instead of child.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 classes to achieve what you want:

```
public class CreateChildRequestDTO {
   @JsonProperty("another parameter")
   private String anotherParameter;

   @JsonProperty("child")
   private ChildDTO child;
}

public class ChildDTO {
   @JsonProperty("childfullname")
   private String childFullName;

   @JsonProperty("password")
   private String password;

   @JsonProperty("phonenumber")
   private String phonenumber;
}
```

and change the Controller method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createchild", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void createChild(@RequestBody CreateChildRequestDTO createChildRequest ) {
    ...
}
```

Beware that in your example you are using an Entity class as a DTO which is a bad practice. This is explained here: [Mixing entity with payload (dto) in spring boot - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651300/mixing-entity-with-payload-dto-in-spring-boot-best-practice).